# What are the minimum IIS AppPool users permissions required for executing hosted Powershell via a WSManConnectionInfo WinRM 'loopback' session in C#?

Tags: c#, powershell

I have a web service running some hosted Powershell. There is authentication at the front-end which passes credentials down to some impersonation in C#.

The application runs as the default IIS AppPool user. More or less everything ends up impersonated. 
This works perfectly - although I had to tweak the .NET 'alwaysFlowImpersonationPolicy' setting as I discovered here:

[Invoking Powershell via C# in a web application - issues with app pool identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18620440/invoking-powershell-via-c-sharp-in-a-web-application-issues-with-app-pool-iden)

In an answer to the question above, it was also suggested I could use WinRM as an alternative method for executing the Powershell, which I didn't choose to do at the time.

For a bunch of different reasons I would like to experiment with doing away with the C# impersonation and move all of the permission elevation to WinRM. I am led to believe this is possible, although I am happy to acknowledge that it isn’t...

If I do something like this:

```
        PSCredential psc = new PSCredential(user, password);
        WSManConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(new Uri("https://ahostname:5986/wsman"), "http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.PowerShell", psc);
        connectionInfo.AuthenticationMechanism = AuthenticationMechanism.Kerberos;
        connectionInfo.SkipCNCheck = true;
        connectionInfo.SkipCACheck = true;
        using (Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo))
        {
            connectionInfo.EnableNetworkAccess = true;
            using (PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create())
            {

                string existingScript = @"C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1";
                string scriptFileName = Path.GetFileName(existingScript);
                string scriptText = ". " + existingScript + ";  " + command;

                if (command_logging == true)
                {
                    string logMessage = "Running command via PSH wrapper: " + scriptText;
                    Tools.logToFile(logMessage);
                }

                powershell.AddScript(scriptText);
                Collection<PSObject> results = new Collection<PSObject>();
                try
                {
                   results = powershell.Invoke();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                    results.Add(new PSObject((object)ex.Message));

                }

                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                foreach (PSObject obj in results)
                {
                   stringBuilder.AppendLine(obj.ToString());
                }
                string rawReturnValue = stringBuilder.ToString();
                string returnValue = rawReturnValue.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, "");
                returnValue.Trim();
                powershell.Dispose();
                return returnValue;
            }
```

I get a weird set of behaviour:

If my AppPool runs under the default credentials (ApplicationPoolIdentity), 99% of Powershell functions will not  return anything meaningful.

The PSObject 'results' object in the snippet above returns 0. No error at all, it's almost as if it is not executing.

Some functions, 'Get-Process' for example, will return fine.

I thought perhaps my methodology may not transfer to using WSManConnectionInfo (i.e. dot sourcing the profile etc), however if I force the app to run under an administrator account, everything works perfectly (so much so I can swap my new and old Powershell 'wrapper' methods out seamlessly, running a bunch of other tests...)

The two 'default' cmdlets i tested:

'Get-Module'. This is in Microsoft.PowerShell.Core, works under the administrator account but does not work under ApplicationPoolIdentity.

'Get-Process'. Microsoft.PowerShell.Management, works under both ApplicationPoolIdentity and the administrator account.

I then wrapped 'Get-Process' in a test function, put it in my $profile and tried to call that. This works when the AppPool is running under the administrator account but not under the ApplicationPoolIdentity.

Almost certainly a permissions issue? Could someone please point me in the right direction?